# Obtaining flow accumulation from negative elevations using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

I have bathymetric data extracted from INFOMAR ArcGIS grids.

Based on the data I am wondering if the `fill`, `flow direction` and `flow accumulation` tools work with negative elevations or if I have to use the raster calculator to change them to values lying above the sea level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you will have no problem with negative values. I remember that I used these tools for the Jordan River Basin where we had negative elevations wihtout problems. In addition, if you reverse the numbers you will have false result.

Comment: You can always raise Dem to make all values positive.